# Building DC Dashboard with BubbleChart Overlay on Map - Better Example?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm working on a visualization similar to [this example](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/crime/), linked-to by the dc.js library example homepage. The page has some decent example starter code to go by, however I have a particular question about drawing a bubble chart over a map.

In the above example, it appears the author manually assigns the path to display the Canadian province shapes. The code then assigns a `bubbleOverlay` chart to a variable called `caChart`, which will contain the bubbles that are drawn at specific coordinates over the Canadian map. However, further down in the code it looks like the code manually assigns (x, y) coordinates on the webpage for each bubble to be drawn at instead of assigning their locations programmatically (see comments):

```
caChart.width(600)
            .height(450)
            .dimension(cities)
            .group(totalCrimeRateByCity)
            .radiusValueAccessor(function(p) {
                return p.value.avgTotalCrimeRate;
            })
            .r(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 200000]))
            .colors(["#ff7373","#ff4040","#ff0000","#bf3030","#a60000"])
            .colorDomain([13, 30])
            .colorAccessor(function(p) {
                return p.value.violentCrimeRatio;
            })
            .title(function(d) {
                return "City: " + d.key
                        + "\nTotal crime per 100k population: " + numberFormat(d.value.avgTotalCrimeRate)
                        + "\nViolent crime per 100k population: " + numberFormat(d.value.avgViolentCrimeRate)
                        + "\nViolent/Total crime ratio: " + numberFormat(d.value.violentCrimeRatio) + "%";
            })
            // These points appear to be assigned manually
            .point("Toronto", 364, 400)
            .point("Ottawa", 395.5, 383)
            .point("Vancouver", 40.5, 316)
            .point("Montreal", 417, 370)
            .point("Edmonton", 120, 299)
            .point("Saskatoon", 163, 322)
            .point("Winnipeg", 229, 345)
            .point("Calgary", 119, 329)
            .point("Quebec", 431, 351)
            .point("Halifax", 496, 367)
            .point("St. John's", 553, 323)
            .point("Yukon", 44, 176)
            .point("Northwest Territories", 125, 195)
            .point("Nunavut", 273, 188);
```

I have time-stamped data at lat-long coordinates that I would like to plot over a similar map of the United States. The data roughly look something like:

```
device_id, timestamp, lat, lon
1, 2014-7-21, 40.7127837, -74.00594130000002
2, 2014-7-22, 40.8516701, -93.2599318
```

Is there a way to read these coordinates in to a crossfilter dimension, and programmatically plot these coordinates over a similar underlying map image without having to manually assign them? Any help here (including pointers to working examples) would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, the bubble overlay chart is particularly less developed. Do you have a map image that you want to use, and if so, can you figure out the projection? If not, would a linked leaflet chart work?

Comment: @Gordon: a Leaflet chart could work. The underlying image of the US is borrowed from this D3 example (http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bubble-map/), and I believe is projected using the Albers US projection. The other option I was thinking of was to build the US chart with D3 and feed that chart a crossfilter dimension and group. However, I'm unsure on how to go about that. Thanks for reading.

Comment: So, if you're using that map directly, it [specifies](https://gist.github.com/mbostock/9943478#file-makefile-L22-L24) that the projection is `d3.geo.albersUsa().scale(1280).translate([width / 2, height / 2])` - the quickest way to get something working will be to apply that to your points. It would be nice if the bubble overlay chart supported projections, but I suppose it can be used with non-maps, too, so maybe that's why.

Comment: As for the leaflet solution, I started a PR to pull some bubble chart code from one of the dc.leaflet.js forks. But I haven't tested it yet. https://github.com/dc-js/dc.leaflet.js/pull/13

Answer (score 0):

You could bypass the bubble overlay altogether and just use

```
mapChart
.on("renderlet", drawSomething)
```

in the drawSomething method you can programatically draw your bubbles like i outlined here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35476690/2795423